# `fancyhdr` header not showing correctly on chapter page

Tags: fancyhdr, pagestyle

In my LaTeX document, I've used a customized heading.
The code shows accordingly in every page of the document except one. I've copied the exact code I used and inserted it after writing `\newpage`, but sadly it still doesn't show how I'd like, can anyone please help me?
Here is the code I used:

```
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[L]{\textbf {\color{gray} AGYS – Anglické gymnázium a SOŠ, s.r.o.}}
   \fancyhead[R]{\textbf {\color{gray} \thepage}}
   \vspace*{-1.1cm}   
  \color{gray} \hrule
```

I'm also adding pictures of what the code shows incorrectly:

[image]

and correctly on the other pages:

[image]

Comment: Do you have chapters in your document?

Comment: yes, it's divided into 7 sections and there's also a subsection added. This code was used in one of the sections (as a part of the general text within a section)

Comment: chapters have the pagestyle `plain` and not `fancy`! If you want headers on the first chapter page then define `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}`.  See documentation, page 12f

Comment: so you mean I could use this code only when there is a new chapter on the page, or to not use it and change it completely?

Comment: your code is for all pages, except the first one of a chapter. As I wrote: Read the documentation ...

Comment: ok thank you! :)